# Why do you need induction to show that $x^{a+b}=x^ax^b$ if $x\in G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have seen a couple of proofs online for problem #1.1.19 in Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra that use strong induction to prove the following claim;

> Let $x\in G$ where $G$ is a group.  Let $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}^+$.  Prove $$x^{a+b}=x^ax^b$$

I have not seen any proofs of the following form:

$$x^{a+b}=\underbrace{x\cdot x\cdots x}_{a+b\text{ times}}=\underbrace{x\cdot x\cdots x}_{a\text{ times}}\cdot \underbrace{x\cdot x\cdots x}_{b\text{ times}}=x^ax^b$$

I would assume that with positive integer exponents, this would be the most obvious way to show this is true.  So why the need for induction?

Comment: Because, it's considered too informal.

Comment: Whenever you use dots ($\cdots$), you're likely using induction, just informally.

Comment: Here's an important technicality: *but how do you prove that*
$$
\underbrace{x\cdot x\cdots x}_{a+b\text{ times}}=\underbrace{x\cdot x\cdots x}_{a\text{ times}}\cdot \underbrace{x\cdot x\cdots x}_{b\text{ times}}?
$$

Comment: This $(⋯)$Does not make sense in math.

Comment: But wouldn't that just be addition ('combining' a elements with b elements)?

Comment: @AveryJessup you're assuming that the only piece of information that matters is the number of elements $x$ which are being multiplied.  Implicitly, you're moving around a lot of parentheses:
$$
\underbrace{(((x\cdot x)\cdots )x)}_{a+b\text{ times}}=\underbrace{(((x\cdot x)\cdots )x)}_{a\text{ times}}\cdot \underbrace{(((x\cdot x)\cdots )x)}_{b\text{ times}}
$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that multiplication is defined as a binary operator, not as something you do with a bunch of copies of $x$.  As such, when you declare that 
$$
\underbrace{x\cdot x\cdots x}_{a+b\text{ times}}=\underbrace{x\cdot x\cdots x}_{a\text{ times}}\cdot \underbrace{x\cdot x\cdots x}_{b\text{ times}}
$$
you're *assuming* that the only piece of information that matters is the number of elements x which are being multiplied. That is, you're implicitly moving around a lot of parentheses in the equation
$$
\underbrace{(((x\cdot x)\cdots )x)}_{a+b\text{ times}}=\underbrace{(((x\cdot x)\cdots )x)}_{a\text{ times}}\cdot \underbrace{(((x\cdot x)\cdots )x)}_{b\text{ times}}
$$
You'll notice that the inductive step  in the proof only requires that we deal with one reordering at a time, as in
$$
x^{a+1} \cdot x^b = (x \cdot x^a) \cdot x^b = x \cdot (x^a \cdot x^b) = x \cdot x^{a + b} = x^{a + b + 1}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Because, it's considered too informal. To be formal, one needs to use the *definition* of $x^n$, and the definition is *not* the product of $n$ copies of $x$.

Since for nonnegative integers $n$, the definition of $x^n$ is an inductive definition, a formal proof of that identity is pretty much forced to use induction.

Comment: If the definition of $x^n$ was repeated multiplication, would the proof in the OP still be considered too informal?

Comment: Such a definition would itself lack formality. The whole point of the inductive definition was to make the meaning rigorous.

Comment: Okay.  I think I understand

Comment: Still, when we work with powers, we don't _think_ inductively -- that's too primitive. We revert conceptually to the informal "repeated multiplication" version. And once the basic identities are proved, the inductive definition is essentially no longer needed.