# To prove that $a^m.a^n=a^{m+n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, exponentiation

> In a group $G$, I want to prove this theorem:
>
> $$\forall a\in G,\; a^m.a^n=a^{m+n},\;m,n\in \Bbb Z.$$

I am thinking that only associative law is sufficient to prove this.please give some suggestions or hint to prove this.thanks in advance

Comment: in MathJax  it can be rewritten as $\forall a\in G,a^m\cdot a^n=a^{n+m}$

Comment: Yeah I changed that.it is a typographical error

Comment: Try induction on $n$.

Comment: Yeah I tried..I need some assistance

Comment: Note that this question is an exact duplicate of  [Why to you need induction to show that $x^{ab} = x^ax^b$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2294918/why-do-you-need-induction-to-show-that-xab-xaxb-if-x-in-g)

Comment: Be careful when considering your choice of answer to accept, Sathasivam; the better answer is given in the answers at [Why do you need induction to show that $x^{ab} = x^ax^b](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2294918/why-do-you-need-induction-to-show-that-xab-xaxb-if-x-in-g)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is clear that $a^{m+1}=a^m.a$. On the other hand, if $a^{m+n}=a^m.a^n$, then$$a^{m+n+1}=a^{m+n}.a=a^m.a^n.a=a^m.a^{n+1}.$$

Comment: @Sathasivam : Note that this indeed only uses associativity, as you mentioned at the end of your question

Comment: @santos But what about negative integers sir.

Comment: If $m=0$ or $n=0$, it is trivial. If $m>0>n$, and $m+n>0$, then $a^m=a^{-n}.a^{m+n}$ and therefore $a^m.a^n=a^{m+n}$. If $m>0>n$ and $m+n<0$, then $a^{m}.a^{-m-n}=a^{-n}$ and therefore $a^m.a^n=a^{m+n}$. And so on...

Comment: Is this supposed to be a proof by induction on $n$?  You might want to make it more explicitly so.

Comment: In any case, the question has been closed, as it ought to have been.

Comment: Note that this answer is an exact duplicate of  the answer(s) at [Why to you need induction to show that $x^{ab} = x^ax^b$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2294918/why-do-you-need-induction-to-show-that-xab-xaxb-if-x-in-g)

Comment: @amWhy Yes, it was supposed to be a proof by induction. And it is hard for me to see how could I have been more explicit, other than using the word “induction” itself. That would have made the *method* of proof explicit, but the proof would not have become more correct then.

Answer (score 3):

Write out what each exponent means. We have
$$\begin{align}
a^ma^n&=\underbrace{a\times \dots \times a}_{m\text{ times}}\times\underbrace{a\times \dots \times a}_{n\text{ times}} \\
&=\underbrace{a\times \dots \times a}_{m+n\text{ times}} \\
&=a^{m+n}.
\end{align}$$

Yes, associativity is thus sufficient.

Comment: While this proof is intuitive and useful, it is not totally rigorous, as explained [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2294918/81360)

Comment: Note @Omnomnomnom, that you would have been much more helpful to raise this linked post of which this post is a duplicate.  It seems to me, this OP here, for this question, is in need of an intuitive understanding of this as much as s/he is in need of a formal proof.

Comment: Shaun, I think your post.  The accepted post is not entirely rigorous, either. It is not a rigorous proof by induction on $n$,

Comment: @amWhy again, we have a difference of opinion.  The linked post has a much different emphasis; it was asked by someone who is expressly familiar with how the proof is supposed to look. Since the answers on that post were geared towards that question, neither of them provide what the asker of this post is apparently trying to ask for.  Then again, the answers here don't really do that either.  Then again, OP didn't exactly provide all the context he should have.  In the end, I think it's appropriate that the question was closed for lack of context rather than as a duplicate.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  Well, you and I agree that the question be closed for lack of context,

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  Well, you and I agree that the question be closed for lack of context,  How ever, I don't see your vote to close the question for lack of context.  Given the fact that we agree that there is insufficient context to render any answer to it possibly problematic, I suggest that you **do not single out any answerers' answer as correct, and the other wrong,